# Parse data from array in JSON with php

Tags: php, json

```
{"type":"result","data":[{"title":"Web Radio \u0391\u03a5\u039b\u0391\u0399\u0391","song":"ELENI XATZIDOU - DEN 8A SE PERIMENW","track":{"artist":"ELENI XATZIDOU","title":"DEN 8A SE PERIMENW","album":"WEB RADIO AYLAIA","royaltytrackid":7385.0000,"id":7385,"playlist":{"id":133,"title":"03.Tetarti"},"buyurl":"","imageurl":"http:\/\/188.40.166.136:2197\/static\/ilias\/covers\/rsz_emb_eleni_xatzidou_den_8a_se_perimenw_eeec1cadjpg"},"bitrate":"192 Kbps","server":"Online","autodj":"Online","source":"Yes","offline":false,"summary":"<a href=\"http:\/\/188.40.166.136:2199\/tunein\/-stream\/ilias.pls\">Web Radio \u0391\u03a5\u039b\u0391\u0399\u0391 - ELENI XATZIDOU - DEN 8A SE PERIMENW<\/a>","listeners":1,"maxlisteners":150,"reseller":0,"serverstate":true,"sourcestate":true,"sourceconn":true,"date":"Oct 15, 2014","time":"06:51 PM","rawmeta":"ELENI XATZIDOU - DEN 8A SE PERIMENW ","url":"http:\/\/188.40.166.136:2199\/rpc"}]}
```

I have the above JSON file and I would like to get the song title ("ELENI XATZIDOU - DEN 8A SE PERIMENW"). I would like to do it with php. I'm very new in JSON and I think that it will be not very defficult for some of you.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to `$data = json_decode($json_str)` the string and access to $data['data']['song']

Comment: @Sal00m Actually that would produce an object, not an array, and therefore your code will throw an error, either use `echo $data->data[0]->song;` or use `json_deocde($json_str, 1);` to convert it to an associative array.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried it and it's OK. If you would like give it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy are right json_decode withut second parameter return object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stdObj = json_decode($json);
echo $stdObj->data[0]->song;
```

or

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['data'][0]['song'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data = '{"type":"result","data":[{"title":"Web Radio \u0391\u03a5\u039b\u0391\u0399\u0391","song":"ELENI XATZIDOU - DEN 8A SE PERIMENW","track":{"artist":"ELENI XATZIDOU","title":"DEN 8A SE PERIMENW","album":"WEB RADIO AYLAIA","royaltytrackid":7385.0000,"id":7385,"playlist":{"id":133,"title":"03.Tetarti"},"buyurl":"","imageurl":"http:\/\/188.40.166.136:2197\/static\/ilias\/covers\/rsz_emb_eleni_xatzidou_den_8a_se_perimenw_eeec1cadjpg"},"bitrate":"192 Kbps","server":"Online","autodj":"Online","source":"Yes","offline":false,"summary":"<a href=\"http:\/\/188.40.166.136:2199\/tunein\/-stream\/ilias.pls\">Web Radio \u0391\u03a5\u039b\u0391\u0399\u0391 - ELENI XATZIDOU - DEN 8A SE PERIMENW<\/a>","listeners":1,"maxlisteners":150,"reseller":0,"serverstate":true,"sourcestate":true,"sourceconn":true,"date":"Oct 15, 2014","time":"06:51 PM","rawmeta":"ELENI XATZIDOU - DEN 8A SE PERIMENW ","url":"http:\/\/188.40.166.136:2199\/rpc"}]}';


$json_decode = json_decode($data);

echo $json_decode->data[0]->song;

?>
```